# javascript: closures, anonymous functions, iife

Tags: closures, anonymous-function, iife, lexical-scope

A friend asked me to design a function that does the following : `f1()()()()(0)`
should give the output as 4. `f1()(0)` should give output as 1. It is the number of preceding parentheses before 0 is passed. I searched thoroughly on how it should be done. Got some concepts to string together: like IIFE, Anonymous Functions and Lexical Scope. Does this use a more advanced javascript concept function that should be known? 
[Here is the image of what needs to be done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmNKt.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

No advanced concepts. You only need to know how to return a function from another function.

---

I would prefer to call the function `f0` because `f0(0)` obviously should return `0`. Then we can imagine all such kinds of functions that return their level of parenthetication—for example, `f42(0)` returns `42`.

When called without a parameter, `f0()` should return `f1`, so that `f0()(0)` is `1`, and so on. That is an easy thing to do:

```
function f0(x) {
  return (x === 0) ? 0 : f1(x);
}
```

Obviously, we do not want to write down an infinity of functions like this. Let's make a function factory that will build them automatically as needed:

```
function factory(level) {
  function f_level(x) {
    return (x === 0) ? level : factory(level + 1);
  }
  return f_level;
}
```

The factory always returns a function, and `factory(0)` is exactly the function `f0` you wanted.